# Где асинхронно обновлять инфу для вложенных компонентов React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пробую ReactJS. В приложении есть список, внутри строк которого – еще по два списка. Примерно такая структура компонентов:

```
App: {
  List: [
    ListItem: {
      A: SubList[ SublistItem, ..],
      B: SubList[ SublistItem, ..]
    }
  ]
}
```

Самые вложенные `SubListItem` отображают объекты стороннего сервиса, у которых много характеристик, но у меня хранятся только их id. Остальные данные предстоит получить асинхронно через api того сервиса. В ходе работы с приложением они не меняются и нужны только для отображения.

При загрузке приложения корневой App получает id и передаёт их вглубь.

**Вопрос**, где запрашивать доп. инфу: непосредственно из каждого конечного экземпляра `SubListItem`, сохраняя в `state`; или делать это выше по иерархии и передавать «вниз» через `props`?

---

**Разобрался:** запрашиваю из конечных потребителей этой инфы.

Использую собственную кэширующую «прослойку», т.к. инфа об одном объекте может понадобиться нескольким потребителям.

Comment: Почему не захотели в качестве решения выбрать redux?